The representation has finite kernel.
Let  $\rho: \Gamma \rightarrow \text{Isom} (\mathbb H^n)$  is a representation of finitely generated group $\Gamma$.  Let $x_0 \in \mathbb H^n$ and  the orbit map $\tau_\rho: \Gamma \rightarrow \mathbb H^n$ defined by $\gamma \mapsto \rho(\gamma)\cdot x_0$ is a quasi isometric embedding, i.e. $\forall \gamma , \gamma'\in \Gamma$ $${\frac{1}{A}}d_{S}(\gamma, \gamma')-B\leq d_{\mathbb H^n}(\tau_\rho (\gamma),\tau_\rho (\gamma'))\leq A d_{S}(x,y)+ B$$ where $d_S$ is the word metric on $\Gamma$.
I want to prove that $\rho $ has finite kernel.
My attempt: Let $x_0 \in \mathbb H^n$. I have proved that $\text{Ker}(\rho)  \subset \tau_{\rho}^{-1}(x_0)$. Now if we prove $\tau_{\rho}^{-1}(x_0)$ has finite no. of elements then we are done. Now if $\gamma\in \tau_{\rho}^{-1}(x_0)$ then $\rho(\gamma) \in \text{Stab}(x_0)$. But I could not proceed more. Please help.

Assume that $\gamma \in \ker \rho$.
Let $1_{\Gamma}$ be the neutral element of $\Gamma$.
Then $1_{\Gamma}\cdot x_0 = \gamma\cdot x_0 = x_0$, and therefore
$$
d_S(1_{\Gamma},\gamma) \leqslant AB + A\,\underbrace{d(\tau_{\rho}(1_{\Gamma}),\tau_{\rho}(\gamma))}_{=0} = AB.
$$
Hence $\gamma \in B_{\Gamma}(1; AB)$.
Since $\Gamma$ is finitely generated, $B_{\Gamma}(1_{\Gamma};AB)$ is finite.
It follows that $\ker \rho \subset B_{\Gamma}(1_{\Gamma};AB)$ is finite.

Thank you very much.
